# Predicting all zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I've depeloped a neural network for classification and I'm getting a 0.93 of accuracy, the problem is that I'm predicting all zeros because the distribution of the data.

[image: Data distribution]

How can I fix it? Should I change from neural network to another algorithm?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: i've just checked and my model is predicting the same probability for each row.

The model is a NN with 5 layers, and `tf.nn.relu6` as activation function. The cost function is `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`

To predict the values I use:

```
predicted = tf.nn.sigmoid(Z5)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.round(predicted), Y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

**EDIT 2**

I have 'fixed' the imbalance class problem (undersampling and upsampling 0s and 1s) but the net is still predicting the same values for each row:

[image: Prediction]

I have tested to change activation function to tanh or sigmoid but then outputs NaN's

Comment: Please supply info on what model are you using, what is the data, and the code.

Comment: Google "class imbalance"...

Comment: In practise I have seen two possible fixes for that (although I dislike both of them). The first is to throw away parts of the dataset so that all outcomes are equally likely. The other one is to put some samples - namely those with a prediction outcome that is not occuring to often - multiple times into the dataset. With both ways all prediction results become about equally likely in the traning set. If someone knows another way I would be interested in it too.

Comment: @quent class imbalance is a huge subtopic, and there are are several other approaches, like creating artificial samples of the minority class; look for SMOTE & RUSBoost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for unbalanced data. But first, the accuracy is not a good metric for unbalanced data, because if you only had 5 positives and 95 negatives, you accuracy will be 95% of predicting negatives. You should check **sensitivity and specificity**, or other metrics that work good with unbalanced data like the **LIFT score**.

To train the model with unbalanced data, there are multiple solutions. One of them is the U**p-sample Minority Class**.

> Up-sampling is the process of randomly duplicating observations from
>   the minority class in order to reinforce its signal.

You can upsample data with a code like this:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
# Separate majority and minority classes
df_majority = df[df.balance==0]
df_minority = df[df.balance==1]

# Upsample minority class
df_minority_upsampled = resample(df_minority, 
                                 replace=True,     # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=576,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=123) # reproducible results

# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
df_upsampled = pd.concat([df_majority, df_minority_upsampled])

# Display new class counts
df_upsampled.balance.value_counts()
# 1    576
# 0    576
# Name: balance, dtype: int64
```

You can find more information and other solutions that are well explained [here](https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes).